# Serializing localised resources into .NET satellite assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

I'm migrating a .NET Framework class library to .NET, and some of the things the library does are parsing a .NET assembly, extracting any localisable resources, and creating satellite assemblies containing localised versions of those resources, which may include strings, images, or forms.

We parse the resources in an assembly using DeserializingResourceReader which gives us a dictionary, from which we obtain and store the string representations of the resource name, value and type. Once localised, we convert the resource info from strings back into their types using a TypeConverter instance, before passing them to ResourceWriter.AddResource(string,object) and calling ResourceWriter.Generate(), but this doesn't seem to work in .NET, as it throws a PlatformNotSupportedException warning that "This platform does not support binary serialized resources."

According to Microsoft docs, fewer types can be serialized into .resources files than in .NET Framework. I checked the source code for ResourceWriter.Generate() and there is indeed a method called FindTypeCode which checks the types of each resource being serialized against a fixed list such as string, int etc. If it doesn't find a match, it throws the PlatformNotSupportedException.

I couldn't find any alternative approaches we could use instead, so I'm a bit stumped and would appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the binaryformaters. Please check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete

Comment: please explain per guidelines